# Why can I not get Remix to deploy to Polygon Mainnet?

Tags: solidity, remix, polygon

I have a contract that I have deployed to both Ropsten and Fantom Mainnet. I want to try it with Polygon. I have plenty of Matic, the contract compiles, but when I try to deploy it I get the error:

```
Creation of Collection errored: Non-200 status code: '403'
{
"message";"forbidden"
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably not caused by the contract or the deployment.

non-200 status

When you contact the RPC to deploy you don't get an OK http 200 status.
This mean that you can not connect to it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200

the other code 403 if from the http protocol.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Your errors are related to the connection with the RPC endpoint your trying to connect to.

Double check your network settings.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What is weird to me, and I just tried it again now, is that I can take the same contract and deploy it on Ropsten and Fantom. It is just with Polygon for whatever reason I get this error.

Comment: Maybe check all the addresses your using. But again it has nothing to do with the actual deployment. You can't connect to the rpc to deploy your contract.

Comment: You were right. I changed the RPC to https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com instead of https://rpc-mainnet.matic.network and I could deploy my contract. Thanks again!